# Large Video Upload HTML5

Tags: html, video, file-upload, upload, streaming

I've seen using the html5 api it's possible to record/upload video content straight from the browser.   This issue in a project I'm currently working on is the video recordings can be very long/big and I'd like to mitigate upload time for the user.

Ideally the video would be uploaded in one of two ways:

1. As it's being recorded (streaming upload).
2. For worse network connections, upload the video in smaller chunks (so store locally and then upload a chunk every 5 minutes, let's say).

Does anyone have any guidance on if these could practically work with the current level of html5 functionality and if so, if there any good resources on the subject?

Comment: look at vendors with webRTC libs where you could ... stream audio and video on separate sockets if that makes better use of bandwidth, possibly adjusting for network variables. "Layer" is sort of an example of one of these vendors but dont think they focus on webRTC which others do.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC based MediaStream Recording (http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/) sounds like it is what you are looking for, as Robert suggest in the comments.

There is a Javascript library available on GitHub which looks like it should meet your needs:

- https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

In particular they note:

> MediaStreamRecorder is useful in scenarios where you're planning to submit/upload recorded blobs in realtime to the server! You can get blobs after specific time-intervals.